# Parsing Response Html - from Node Request Package

Tags: html, json, node.js, parsing, request

I'm trying to request data from a public LinkedIn page using the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) Node Package. I was using [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse the response but it mysteriously started returning undefined when I would try to use the filter isolate data.

This was my request parse code:

```
 var $ = cheerio.load(html);

//COMPANY
    $('div .image-wrapper img').filter(function(){
        company = $(this);
        company = company.attr('alt');
        if (typeof company != 'string') {
            company = "Not Available";
        }
        console.log("Scraping " + company + ": URL #" + counter + " of " + urls.length);
        inArr.push(company);            
   })
```

So I had the idea that maybe I could parse the response manually and find what I'm looking for and then find a way to get it in the code. So I console logged the response and got a really REALLY long response. The data was formatted like JSON. With the "body" key, being the last item in the object.

I'll paste below an excerpt that contains the data but I can't paste the whole thing.

The key/value essentially begins like this:

```
body: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

And contains a lot of data stored in what appear to be html comments like this:

```
<!--{"specialties":["forwarding","supply chain",
"supply chain management","supply chain development","reefer logistics",
"ocean freight","airfreight","landside services","transport documents",
"cargo insurance","customs clearance","trucking","haulage","warehouse",
"distribution","retail logistics"],"squareLogo":"/
```

The frustrating thing is that the data that I need is right there in the response but I have no idea what this is or how to parse it. I tried using JSON.parse and various other html parsing Node Packages. Does anyone know a parser that would be good to use for this? Thanks!